# PS Script for filtering registry installed programs

Tags: powershell, registry, administration

I'm an IT administrator in my company and im trying to find out if people installed things they shouldn't have...

To do that, im using PS to access the registry and output a list of values from the Uninstall key. however, i am only starting to use Powershell, and am very new to it.

Eventually i want this script to go over the entire Domain and look into the registry values and output a list of programs that are not supposed to be installed.

the script i've written so far:

```
$path = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Get-ItemProperty -Name DisplayName
```

and it's output:

```
DisplayName  : Intel(R) Chipset Device Software
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{C965318A-AA36-4F94-9ED5-AE5391F452B2}
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName  : {C965318A-AA36-4F94-9ED5-AE5391F452B2}
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

DisplayName  : Intel(R) ME UninstallLegacy
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{DF17C0DB-76D8-4A45-B26E-674F8455B803}
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName  : {DF17C0DB-76D8-4A45-B26E-674F8455B803}
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry

DisplayName  : VMware Workstation
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F4C0A853-FA3B-4404-954B-799299EB5A98}
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
PSChildName  : {F4C0A853-FA3B-4404-954B-799299EB5A98}
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

very basic i know, but it does output the list i want it to, but no matter how much i mess around with the filter or exclude cmdlets, i cant manage to make it leave out of the list registry keys that i know should be there.

now lets say i know and am fine with Intel chipset and Intel ME uninstall legacy, so i dont want them to show up on the list, but i'm not fine with VMware workstation, so i do want it to show up when i run the script, how do i do that?

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem -Path $path).Name | Split-Path -Leaf` or even its simpler variant should work as well: `Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Split-Path -Leaf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a list of all *display names* (sorted for better manipulation in the next step):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Get-ItemProperty -Name DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).DisplayName | Sort
```

Then, copy obtained list to `$allowed` here string in the following code snippet (however you can add or remove some items here):

```
$allowed = @"
Intel(R) Chipset Device Software
Intel(R) ME UninstallLegacy
Intel® Trusted Connect Service Client
Microsoft Silverlight
NVIDIA 3D Vision Driver 376.53
NVIDIA Control Panel 376.53
NVIDIA Display Container
NVIDIA Display Container LS
NVIDIA Graphics Driver 376.53
NVIDIA HD Audio Driver 1.3.34.17
Windows App Certification Kit Native Components
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$path = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

(Get-ChildItem -Path $path | 
    Get-ItemProperty -Name DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).DisplayName |
     Where-Object {$_ -notin $allowed} | Sort
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. im not sure why, but when i first tried it, it didnt do anything... not sure what changed

Answer (score 0):

You want a list like that:

```
 Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate
```

Edit:
Here is a quick and dirty solution for the question in the comment.

```
$a = @(Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select     DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate)
$exclud = "Program1","Program2"

for($i = 0; $i -le $a.Count;$i++){
    if($exclud -notcontains $a[$i].DisplayName){
        $a[$i]
    }
}
```

Comment: that is better actually, thank you. but do you know how i can reform the list to exclude programs that should be there and only show the others?

Comment: @ITTom take a look in the answer there is an example for this.

Comment: haha quick and dirty is a good description for it, thank you guiwhatsthat, but i'm very satisfied with JosefZ's code (its also a little more elegant :) )